# SQLITE multiple column index vs. single column indices

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing

Can somebody tell me if with the following SQLite statement..

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  category_id INT  NOT NULL, /* foreign key on `categories` */
  product_id  TEXT NOT NULL, /* must be string, unique only within a category */
  info        TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (category_id, product_id) /* our PK */
  ) WITHOUT ROWID
```

... if I should still construct following indexes

```
CREATE INDEX products_by_category_id
  ON products(category_id)
CREATE INDEX products_by_product_id
  ON products(product_id) /* not sure I need this one at all */
```

or if this is redundant somehow due to multiple column PK INDEX define in the `CREATE TABLE`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is redundant.

Index columns can be used from left to right. E.g. the PK index can be used with `category_id` alone or `category_id` and `product_id` together. Hence an index on `category_id` alone is useless while the one on `product_id` might be useful if you have queries that filter on `product_id` but not on `category_id`.